# JQuery UI Autocomplete reformats source data

Tags: jquery-ui-autocomplete

I format strings as desired for an input with the jquery ui autocomplete:

```
var names = [];
names.push("Test 1");
names.push("Test  2");
names.push("Test   3");
names.push("Test    4");
names.push("Test     5");

$("#search").autocomplete({

    source: names,
    minLength: 3

});
```

Everything works fine and the items are pushed correctly to the array.
But when i use it in my website the output is as follows:

[image: Wrong output]

How can this be solved?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by my own.
Add this to the specific css file:

```
.ui-autocomplete > .ui-menu-item > .ui-menu-item-wrapper {
    white-space: pre;
    font-family:monospace;
}
```